# How to write the equation of an off-center circle in terms of r (parameterization)

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, polar-coordinates

I've looked around online for a while and I can't seem to find a question that properly captures what I'm talking about (or answers that really help me).

For a homework problem, I have to find the area bounded by $x^{2} + y^{2} = 4$ and $(x-1)^{2} + (y-1)^2 = 1$ using double integrals in polar form. I can easily parameterize the first equation as just $r = 2$ using simple algebra.

However, for the second equation, I get stuck quickly. I can first expand the equation to get $x^{2} -2x + 1 + y^{2} -2y + 1 = 1$. I can simplify to get $x^2 + y^2 + 1 = 2(x + y)$. From here I can substitute the polar equivalents of x and y, to get

$r^2 + 1 = 2\big(rcos(\theta) + rsin(\theta)\big)$

From here I have no idea what to do. The math to get here seems simple enough, yet it's somehow wrong.

Once I have the second equation in terms of $r$, I'd imagine I could set the two equations equal to each other, and find at what angles they are equal (giving me the range of $\theta$ over which I need to integrate), then I'd have the second integral for $r$ to be over the bounds of the two equations. But then, I don't know what function I'd be integrating over that specific range.

Thanks for any help. I really am at a loss as to where to turn

Answer (score 1):

In fact this polar equation is in two parts ($r_1$ and $r_2$: see equations (2) and (3) below) which is not surprising when you consider figure 1.

Write your equation under the form:

$$r^2 - 2r\underbrace{(\cos(\theta) + \sin(\theta))}_{f(\theta)}+1=0 \tag{0}$$

and consider it as a quadratic equation, or even simpler as factorisable under the form:

$$[r-f(\theta)]^2+\underbrace{1-f(\theta)^2}_{-2 \sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)}=0$$

Consequently

$$[r-f(\theta)]^2=2 \sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)=\sin(2\theta)$$

which means:

$$r-f(\theta)=\pm \sqrt{\sin(2\theta)}\tag{1}$$

under the condition that $\theta$ belongs to the first quadrat:

$$0\le \theta \le \pi/2$$

in order that $\sin(2\theta) \ge 0$ (needed for taking the square root in (1)).

The previous expressions gives rise to 2 polar equations:

$$r_1=\cos(\theta) + \sin(\theta)-\sin(2\theta) \ \ \ \ \text{(blue arc below)}\tag{2}$$

$$r_2=\cos(\theta) + \sin(\theta)+\sin(2\theta) \ \ \ \ \text{(red arc below)}\tag{3}$$

[image]

*Fig. 1: the two circles.*

Important remark: you need only the blue arc of the second circle.

Another remark: If you want to consider (0) as a quadratic equation, you will find the same $r_1$ and $r_2$ as its roots using discriminant:

$$\Delta=4((\cos(\theta) + \sin(\theta))^2-1)=4(2\cos(\theta)\sin(\theta))=4 \sin(2\theta) $$

Comment: Thanks a ton for the reply. I'm just a little confused as to what I'm finding by finding the "zeros" of the equation. The process to obtain them makes sense, but where do they fit into the general process?

Comment: I'm confused with the 2nd and 3rd equations. When I plug either into desmos for polar equations, neither look like the arcs that are part of the original circle. Thanks for the detailed response

Comment: On Desmos, do you restrict the range of $\theta$ to $(0,\pi/2)$.? Otherwise, you get weird things....

Comment: Finally, have you succeeded ?

Answer (score 0):

Introduce two *different* polar coordinates (let's call them $s$ and $\phi$, just so that we don't confuse them with $r$ and $\theta$), where:

- $s$ is the length of a vector pointing from the center of the circle
  to some point in space, and
- $\phi$ is the angle that vector makes
  with the positive $x$-axis.

Then the conversion between these new coordinates and the usual rectangular coordinates is:
$$ x = 1 + s \cos \phi \\ y = 1 + s\sin \phi$$
and the equation of the circle is $s = 1$.